# how can I change label of xml field into a different string uding .ini file?

Tags: php, xml, joomla

I am in a big stuck for about last 23 days..

I am trying to create a joomla module where I will be able to change the **field label** with another text.

I am showing what I want to do. Please suggest me or if you know the solution than please let me know.

I am working on joomla 3.x .

Now the problem is below.

in xml file there is a field which is like:

```
             <field
                name="slides"
                type="slidesmanager"
                label="MOD_SLIDES_LABEL"
                description="MOD_SLIDES_DESC"
                filter="raw"
            />
```

here the lable is **MOD_SLIDES_DESC** and I want to show it as **slides**

So I created a .ini file in the language folder and put **MOD_SLIDES_DESC='slides'**. but this is not working.

Please suggest me how I can do this. also I want to add javascript in the jooma administrator section and how I can do that too...

waiting for your kind reply..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This clearly is a pure Joomla question, I suggest you delete the XML and PHP tag to attract more audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the modules folder will be a file called like

mod_[modulename].xml

in that file should be a language xml item that points to the ini file.

```
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_[modulename].ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_[modulename].sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

during the install process joomla will read this and assiociate the ini files with the module.

you will probably have to re-install the module to get it to work now.

https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files

Comment: Dear Sean, I tried doing that before you gave me this solution, but still not working for joomla 3.x ..
although thanks. Please let me know if you get any other answer.